# please tell me how to write code for chrome extension to be in full screen

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

Presently I am using this code in my popup.js enter code here:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse){ 
    console.log(sender)
    console.log(sender.tab.windowId)
    var wid = sender.tab.windowId
    chrome.windows.update(wid, { state: "fullscreen" })
});
```

This is my complete code of popup.js
This code first find the window Id and then through that window Id want to settle to the full screen. 
This will gives an Error Uncaught Refrence Window Id is Not Defined 
and a yellow Blink line on line no 1 (chrome.runtime.onMessage.......)

Answer (score 0):

Simple just complete this steps.
**Step 1:** Left click on chrome icon
**Step 2:** Go to properties.
**Step 3:** In the target field add/append the following text to the end after a space: **--kiosk-printing --kiosk**
**Step 4:** It will a poor solution but it works

Comment: ibnelaiq:  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk-printing --kiosk     (I Just Complete Your Steps But Nothing Happen), But I Want to say Something I Want This Thing Dynamically when Users CLick on my Extension then I want to open in a full page (within a chrome Window)